# What can cause a join to be slower than dividing to two queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, faceted-search

I'm performing JOIN from multiple tables to perform a faceted search. When avoiding the JOIN and dividing the query into two different ones I've noticed a big performance boost, so I assume my JOIN isn't optimized.

The structure:

```
-- tags
userId  |   tagId
1              3
1              4
2              3
2              9

-- search
userId   |   number  |   countryId   |   stateId ...  
1              13           221             55

-- countries
countryId     |  countryName   
221                 Somewhere

-- users
userId    |   profileImageLink
1         |   <photo link>
```

I'm trying to extract all users that have a tag, order according to search.number and bring meta data from other tables. The query:

```
SELECT 
    search.*, users.a, users.b, users.c, users.d, users.e, users.f, countries.location_country, states.location_state, cities.location_city 
FROM search 
RIGHT JOIN tags 
   ON search.user_id = tags.user_id 
LEFT JOIN users 
   ON users.user_id=search.user_id 
LEFT JOIN countries 
   ON countries.countryId=search.countryId 
LEFT JOIN states 
   ON states.countryId=search.countryId AND states.stateId=search.stateId 
LEFT JOIN cities 
   ON cities.countryId=search.countryId AND cities.stateId=search.stateId AND cities.cityId=search.cityId 
WHERE 
  tags.skillId =52772 
ORDER BY 
  search.number DESC LIMIT 0,200
```

I've noticed removing the JOIN to the users table (and doing that afterwards) makes the query much faster. How can I optimize it to work in the same query? I've tried changing the FROM to tags instead of search, but that didn't work...

This is what EXPLAIN shows:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  tags    ref skill_user,skillId  skill_user  4   const   184854  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  search  eq_ref  user_id user_id 4   tags.user_id    1   
1   SIMPLE  countries   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 2   search.countryId    1   
1   SIMPLE  states  eq_ref  PRIMARY,state   PRIMARY 3   search.stateId  1   
1   SIMPLE  cities  eq_ref  PRIMARY,city    PRIMARY 3   search.cityId   1   
1   SIMPLE  users   eq_ref  user_id user_id 4   search.user_id  1   

EXPLAIN without the LEFT JOIN users:

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  tags    ref skill_user,skillId  skill_user  4   const   155870  Using index
1   SIMPLE  search  eq_ref  user_id user_id 4   tags.user_id    1   
1   SIMPLE  countries   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 2   search.countryId    1   
1   SIMPLE  states  eq_ref  PRIMARY,state   PRIMARY 3   search.stateId  1   
1   SIMPLE  cities  eq_ref  PRIMARY,city    PRIMARY 3   search.cityId   1
```

EXPLAIN of query suggested in answer:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  tags    index   NULL    userid_skill    8   NULL    22689539    Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  search  eq_ref  user_id user_id 4   tags.user_id    1   
1   SIMPLE  users   eq_ref  user_id user_id 4   search.user_id  1   
1   SIMPLE  countries   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 2   search.countryId    1   
1   SIMPLE  states  eq_ref  PRIMARY,state   PRIMARY 3   search.stateId  1   
1   SIMPLE  cities  eq_ref  PRIMARY,city    PRIMARY 3   search.cityId   1
```

Comment: Are your columns (on join-columns) properly indexed? Immaterial, I would suggest avoid so many joins. I think splitting queries is a better idea when your data size is potentially going to grow.

Comment: index your join columns and maybe the where columns in your where clauses ... not sure if what i proposed is recommended

Comment: Can you post the "explain" result of your query? Just add EXPLAIN key word in front of your query

Comment: @sdespont Added the EXPLAIN output to the question

Comment: A wrong index is possibly selected: skill_user instead of skillId. Which means that it's got to read all the tags and join all the rest. How many tags do you have with the skillId = 52772?
A quick check can be done by adding `FORCE INDEX(skillId)` after `RIGHT JOIN tags` (I think).

Comment: @ArtemGoutsoul I have 99,834 users with the skillId. However, the force index in this cases goes over a bit more rows than 184k (in other tags in was less but not substantial)

Comment: Can you show EXPLAIN without the users join? can you also provide the running times with and without users join?
p.s.: I would recommend against mixing left and right joins within a long query if you can - much easier to optimize and to understand how MySQL builds it's plan (that's a personal preference, but from years of experience :) )

Comment: @ArtemGoutsoul Added the EXPLAIN without the users join. Running times are at least x10-x20 going up to 300sec.

Comment: There is a table users_skill_ids mentioned in the EXPLAINs but I can't see that table in your query, or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @ArtemGoutsoul that's a typo - fixed, sorry. It's the 'tags' table (that's her real name, thought it would be less confusing here to call her tags)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21691/discussion-between-artem-goutsoul-and-noam)

Comment: @Noam Check the updated answer and update me that changes were works for you or not

Comment: @SaharshShah Thanks very much for your help. I checked your updated answer but it doesn't answer my question. As far as I understand using the sub-query is the same as dividing the task into two queries, which is exactly what I was trying to avoid / understand why it's necessary.

Comment: I want to know other queries are works or not and also it optimise the queries or not

Answer (score 2):

Create Indexes on Tables to run below query:

```
Table    ColumnName
------   ----------
tags     user_id, skillid (Both column in one index)
```

Try this:

```
SELECT s.*, u.a, u.b, u.c, u.d, u.e, u.f, c.location_country, 
       st.location_state, ct.location_city 
FROM tags t 
LEFT JOIN search s ON t.user_id = s.user_id 
LEFT JOIN users u ON t.user_id = u.user_id 
LEFT JOIN countries c ON s.countryId = c.countryId 
LEFT JOIN states st ON s.stateId = st.stateId 
LEFT JOIN cities ci ON s.cityId= ct.cityId 
WHERE t.skillId =52772 
ORDER BY s.number DESC 
LIMIT 0,200
```

**EDIT**

Try this two queries with proper index and let me know that below queries are work for you or not.

```
SELECT s.*, u.a, u.b, u.c, u.d, u.e, u.f, c.location_country, 
       st.location_state, ct.location_city 
FROM (SELECT user_id FROM tags WHERE t.skillId = 52772) AS t 
LEFT JOIN search s ON t.user_id = s.user_id 
LEFT JOIN users u ON t.user_id = u.user_id 
LEFT JOIN countries c ON s.countryId = c.countryId 
LEFT JOIN states st ON s.stateId = st.stateId 
LEFT JOIN cities ci ON s.cityId= ct.cityId 
ORDER BY s.number DESC 
LIMIT 0,200;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT s.*, u.a, u.b, u.c, u.d, u.e, u.f, c.location_country, 
       st.location_state, ct.location_city 
FROM (SELECT t.user_id, s.* FROM tags t 
      LEFT JOIN search s ON t.user_id = s.user_id  
      WHERE t.skillId = 52772 
      ORDER BY s.number DESC 
      LIMIT 0,200) AS t 
LEFT JOIN users u ON t.user_id = u.user_id 
LEFT JOIN countries c ON s.countryId = c.countryId 
LEFT JOIN states st ON s.stateId = st.stateId 
LEFT JOIN cities ci ON s.cityId= ct.cityId 
ORDER BY s.number DESC 
LIMIT 0,200;
```

Comment: When you run the query upload your output of EXPLAIN statement so I can upnderstand that it works on not

Comment: It's what I thought at first (changing the FROM), but it still does the same. I ran it again to make sure, and also the explain shows the same thing. And he doesn't use the index of both the columns although one exists

Comment: Create merged index on both columns in sequence of user_id and skillid. and use that index in your query as **LEFT JOIN search s USE INDEX (index_1) ON t.user_id = s.user_id**. And update me on the same.

Comment: The index I had was skillId -> user_id, I added  user_id -> skillId like you suggested and tried to inforce the use index, but the explain showed a much worse case (now going over 22M in first step using WHERE)

Comment: Have you created a merged index or both are seperate index?

Comment: One index for the two columns.

Comment: Provide me the output of Explain statement with this index

Comment: Added EXPLAIN output to question